# Wi-Fi connected but no internet access in CentOS-7 machine

Tags: centos, wifi, internet

I can connected to a Wi-Fi network, but not able to access the internet. I can access internet through mobile with same Wi-Fi network. Checked the router settings and there aren't any misconfigurations.

I have tried following solutions but they do not work:

1. Restart the CentOS-7 machine
2. Restart the router
3. Changed nameserver IP address from gateway address to `8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf` file and tried to ping `8.8.8.8`. But ping fails after 5 to 10 packets received.

Any idea why it can't connect to the internet?

Also checked the `/etc/resov.conf` file, it shows the correct gateway address.

Comment: Check `dmesg` for errors. Check the signal strength.

Comment: What does "ifconfig -a" show you?

Comment: You managed to ping `8.8.8.8` (and you got some replies)?

Comment: resolv.conf is for DNS, so setting it and then pinging 8.8.8.8 changed nothing. Ping google.com to test your DNS. Do you have an IP? Can you ping or cURL in your LAN? Do you have any kind of captive portal? Do you have a default route set? Is your interface showing a lot of dropped packets? There is a lot of information out there troubleshooting questions like this. I urge you to read those on whatever device you used to post this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following page that fixed my dns for Arch Linux ARM. I had to use solution 3 for it to finally work and I also disabled systemd-resolved.

[ping displays "Name or service not known"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518266/ping-displays-name-or-service-not-known)