# "name or service not known" on Arch

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dns

This is a follow up question to
[ping displays "Name or service not known"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518266/ping-displays-name-or-service-not-known)

My laptop with Arch is connected to a fixed IP LAN with a fixed DNS-server. DNS resolving works after executing

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved && sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

but I have to re-execute the above command after a few minutes. DNSEC is set to `allow-downgrade`. How can I avoid having to execute the command every few minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with systemd-resolved, but in the normal usage of systemctl you should just want to do the restart command, i.e. `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`. By including the second half of your command you restart the service and then immediately stop it. Try just restarting it.